# qDebug() stopped to work (no more printing to console) after upgrading to ubuntu 17.10 (and Fedora as well)

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

After upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10, the `qDebug()` macro stopped working and no longer displays the messages on the console.

How can the debug output be re-enabled in order to see the output of the macro on the console?

Comment: Distro upgrades often remove and/or change things, including packages. Have you made sure that *all* the packages that were installed in your 17.04 are *still* present in your 17.10?

Comment: sure, it is an Ubuntu decision to turn off the qDebug output.

Comment: I've seen people get odd behaviors b/c things changed without them realizing... but I don't think your sarcasm/cynicism is going to get you a lot of help here. Good luck.

Comment: Not sarcasm neither cynicism at all. I'm sorry you to read this. The change in qDebug() behaviour needs to be shared to help others in recovering the default qDebug behaviour.

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding your original reply. It had come across that way, but it seems it was simply a language barrier. In any case, my familiarity with `qDebug` was that it would always display on the console unless a no-debug macro had been defined. **EDIT:** I saw the bug report, and I agree with you, it shouldn't have been changed like that by the Ubuntu guys.

Comment: @ray Thank you for fixing my english! It's a lot more readable now!

Comment: No problem. I've edited the question and answer you provided for readability. In addition, I also moved some content from the question into the answer itself (e.g. bug report reference, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further investigation, the issue was traced back to an Ubuntu team decision to silence the Qt's `qDebug` output by default.

See [missing qDebug output when creating QT applications](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/1731646).

The bug report notes that Fedora has made the same change. If you want to re-enable the `qDebug` output, the solution is pretty easy.

The best way is to create this empty file

```
~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini
```

Another solution is to export the following to your environment:

```
QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=true"
```

This setting affects *all* of the Qt-based applications in the system, i.e. it's a system-wide configuration setting that will cause all of them to display their `qDebug` outputs.